# Ajax always goes in error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to call ajax but it always goes in error part. Please help and tell me where I am wrong. I have also tried writing the final value in a text file and it was perfect but don't know why it is not working. I have also checked the URL it is also correct.

PHP Code:

```
public function checkLockBeforeSend()
{
    $mail_key = $_POST['mail_key'];

    $this->load->model('dl_master/email_compose');
    $result = $this->model_dl_master_email_compose->checkLock($mail_key);

    if($result['isopen'] == 1 && $result['openedby'] != $_SESSION['user_id'])
    {
        $this->load->model('dl_common/commonutil');
        $userResult = $this->model_dl_common_commonutil->getUserById($result['openedby']);
        $userName = $userResult['firstname'] . " " . $userResult['lastname'];
        $html = $userName;
    }
    else
    {
        $html = "Empty";
    }

    /* Just to check what value is coming */
    $fp = fopen("C:\\test.txt","w");
    fwrite($fp,$html);
    fclose($fp);

    echo $html;
}
```

Ajax function:

```
function checkLockBeforeSend(mail_key)
{
    var ajaxUrl = "index.php?route=dl_master/email_compose/checkLockBeforeSend&token=" + token;

    $.ajax ({
        url:ajaxUrl,
        type:'post',
        dataType: 'html',
        data:{'mail_key':mail_key},
        success:function (result)
        {
            alert(result);
            if(result.trim() != "Empty")
            {
                 finalResult = confirm(result);
            }
        },
        error: function () 
        {
            alert("An error occurred.");
        }
    });


}
```

Please help me.

Comment: try removing `dataType: 'html'` from your ajax request options

Comment: Not working @Dola. I tried displaying finalResult value after ajax call in alert box. But after that I got first finalResult value alert box and then error alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try `data:{mail_key:mail_key},` instead of `data:{'mail_key':mail_key},`.